# Private route get Authentication before render Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have problem in using `PrivateRoute` for user with authentication.

Since I use redux to catch authentication of an user, I need to wait `state` return from store before rendering component.
If not, the page will be automatically redirect to `login route`.

My problem is that current route will be redirect to login page while waiting authentication result. It will be return page if authenticated.

So I want wait for `authentication result` first. If authenticated, page component will be loaded, if not it will redirect to login page.

Here is my private route with authentication.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, role, ...rest }) => {    
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (          
          <Redirect  to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

const stateStoreToProp = state => ({
  auth: state.loginReducer,
});
export default connect(stateStoreToProp)(PrivateRoute);
```

Here is my login Component for auto redirect.

```
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/choose" } };
  const isAuthenticated = prop.loginReducer.isAuthenticated;
  const user = prop.loginReducer.user;
  if (isAuthenticated && typeof user !== "undefined") {
    history.replace(from);
  }
```

And here is App.js

```
import { loadUser } from './actions/AuthAction';
function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
      store.dispatch(loadUser()); 
    }, []);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <div className="blockcontain">
              <div className="fss">
                <div className="rightSide">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={Login} />
                    <PrivateRoute exact path='/choose' component={Choose} />
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );  
}
```

and LoginReducer

```
import {
  LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOADED, AUTH_ERROR
} from '../actions/typeName';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
const initialState = {
  token: Cookies.get('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  loading: true, 
  user: null
}
const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const {type, payload} = action; 

  switch(type) {
      case USER_LOADED:
        return {
          ...state,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          loading: false,
          user: payload
        };
      case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        Cookies.set('token', payload.access_token, { expires: payload.expires_at });
        return {
          ...state,
          isAuthenticated: true, 
          loading: false
        }
      case AUTH_ERROR:
      case LOGIN_FAIL:
          return {
            ...state,
            token:null,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            loading: true
          }
      default:
          return state;
  }
}

export default loginReducer;
```

I go `choose page`, it will go to login page because the `store for authentication` is not ready.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you navigate to your auth page after logging in?

Comment: you need to use the `PrivateRoute` when `auth` has value otherwise show some kind of `loading`.  if you show some code of how the `PrivateRoute` is used, maybe we could help more

Comment: @TaghiKhavari I updated App.js which contains `loadUser` action, which will return `is Authenticated` for the user.

Comment: Can we see your loginReducer too? `Codesandbox` would be even better

Comment: @MikailBayram I updated loginReducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a loading property to your state and only show the route when fetching has been completed:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, isLoading, role, ...rest }) => {
  if(isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/',
              state: { from: props.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}

const stateStoreToProp = (state) => ({
  isLoading: state.loading,
  auth: state.loginReducer,
})

export default connect(stateStoreToProp)(PrivateRoute)
```

And also add the loading mutations in your reducer, for example:

```
case REQUEST_LOGIN:
      return [...state, isLoading: true];
case LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL:
      return [...state, auth: isAuthenticated, isLoading: false];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see the solution from you

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to add a "loading" key to your auth state, so while it is authenticating the state will be "true" else "false". If it is true you display a loader.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, role, ...rest }) => {
    
  return (
    <>
      {
        auth.loading && (
          <Loader/>
        )
      }

      {
        !auth.loading && (
          (
            <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => auth.isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component {...props} />
              ) : (          
                <Redirect  to={{
                  pathname: "/",
                  state: { from: props.location }
                }} />
              )
            }
          />          
          )          
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}


const stateStoreToProp = state => ({
  auth: state.loginReducer,
});
export default connect(stateStoreToProp)(PrivateRoute);
```